# Java: check an attribute value exists or not in list by annotation

Tags: java, arrays, annotations

As the title, I want to check an attribute value is exists or not in a list by annotation. Ex:

```
private final String[] list = {"a", "b", "c", "d"}
@Includes(list = list)
private String state;
```

but there is an error `Attribute must be constant`
How can I do it ? Btw, is it a good solution to check this by annotation ?
Here is my annotation:

```
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Inherited
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Includes {
    String[] list();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says it clearly:

> The value for annotation attribute Includes.list must be an array initializer

With non-array variables, the value must be final and static, however, there is no way to do this with arrays. It means you have to do this workaround:

```
@Includes(list = {"a", "b", "c", "d"})
private String state;
```

---

Moreover, your array initialization is wrong, use `{}` instead of `[]`.

Comment: Is it a good practice to use annotation to check it include in array ?

Comment: You haven't specified why do you want to check if the array contains a certain value, so I can't give you an answer. Is it because of validations, or do you want to practise annotations on a simple example?

Comment: I am practicing on a simple example